# On-click behavior of buttons in html

Tags: html

I have a CSS script which has 5 buttons.

Clicking the first button should display a text on the same page in a fixed region (maybe by using frames or writing a hidden function and then doing `show()`).

If the second button is clicked, some other text should appear in the earlier region. Similarly for other buttons. What would be the most efficient way of doing this? (Achieving the fastest loading of the page).

Comment: you could try something with tabs: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: i was going to do something horrible like making an array of text and using button id as index to display the text

Comment: which is same like gareths answer below

Comment: jquery tabs is looking awesome. goes well with the look of the page with less coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div id="textcontainer"></div>
<button id="button1" onclick="setText(0);">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="setText(1);">Button 2</button>
<button id="button3" onclick="setText(2);">Button 3</button>
<button id="button4" onclick="setText(3);">Button 4</button>
<button id="button5" onclick="setText(4);">Button 5</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var text = [
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna.',
  'Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus.',
  'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci.',
  'Aenean nec lorem. In porttitor. Donec laoreet nonummy augue.',
  'Suspendisse dui purus, scelerisque at, vulputate vitae, pretium mattis, nunc. Mauris eget neque at sem venenatis eleifend. Ut nonummy.'
  ];

function setText(index){
   var box = document.getElementById('textcontainer'); 
  box.innerHTML = text[index];
}
```

You can see this in action at: http://jsfiddle.net/Wnw7X/

Answer (score 0):

I guess this?

```
<iframe name="content"></iframe>
<a href="page1.html" target="content">Button 1</a>
<a href="page2.html" target="content">Button 2</a>
And so on...
```

Then add some CSS to make them look like buttons (border, background, etc)

Comment: not exactly what i am looking for. i will try to explain my problem in detail, in a while. i am searching myself for solution elsewhere

Comment: Why? You asked for the simplest way. What could be simpler than built-in behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

ok, here is a complete demo - copy all the code and paste your editor. and run.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {

var myArray = ['you click the first button', 'you click the second button', 'you click the third button', 'you click the fourth button', 'you click the fifth button'];

var one = document.getElementById('buttonOne');
var two = document.getElementById('buttonTwo');
var three = document.getElementById('buttonThree');
var four = document.getElementById('buttonFour');
var five = document.getElementById('buttonFive');

one.onclick = clickHandler;
two.onclick = clickHandler;
three.onclick = clickHandler;
four.onclick = clickHandler;
five.onclick = clickHandler;


function clickHandler(evt) {
    //console.log(evt.target.id);
    var header = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
    if(evt.target.id === 'buttonOne') {
        header.innerHTML = myArray[0];
                console.log(myArray[0]);
        console.log('click');
    }
    else if (evt.target.id === 'buttonTwo') {
        header.innerHTML = myArray[1];
    }
    else if (evt.target.id === 'buttonThree') {
        header.innerHTML = myArray[2];
    }
    else if (evt.target.id === 'buttonFour') {
        header.innerHTML = myArray[3];
    }
    else if (evt.target.id === 'buttonFive') {
        header.innerHTML = myArray[4];
    }
}

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="buttonOne">One</button>
<button id="buttonTwo">Two</button>
<button id="buttonThree">Three</button>
<button id="buttonFour">Four</button>
<button id="buttonFive">Five</button>
<h1> </h1>
</body>
</html>
```